# Different Layerslider by page id?

Tags: plugins

I'm in my `header.php` trying to get the layerslider to show depending of page id.

It works for slider 1 and 2. But after slider 2 every page get the slider 2. Slider 3 and 4 is not showing. Why?

```
<?php
if(is_front_page()){layerslider(1);}
else
if(is_page('32'or'36'or'38'or'40')){layerslider(2);}
else
if(is_page('46'or'48'or'52'or'58'or'60'or'62'or'64'or'66'or'69'or'71')){layerslider(3);}
else
if(is_page('161'or'163'or'169'or'173'or'176'or'179'or'182'or'185'or'188'or'191'or'196'or'199'or'202')){layerslider(3);}
else
if(is_page('219'or'221'or'230'or'232'or'234'or'236'or'239'or'244'or'247'or'251'or'264')){layerslider(4);}
else
if(is_page('277')){layerslider(5);}
?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want is_page to accept multiple parameters, you need an array. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page#Examples

```
<?php
if(is_front_page()){layerslider(1);}
else
if(is_page(array(3,36,38,40))){layerslider(2);}
else
if(is_page(array(46,48,52,58,60,62,64,66,69,71))){layerslider(3);}
else
(…)
?>
```

Should work. And you don't need to quote page id's